# Get dependencies Using ASM5.0.2

Tags: java

I have a Java program based on [ASM 5.0.2](http://asm.ow2.org/) to extract dependency between classes. The program works fine with an ordinary Java application. However, when I run the program as a plugin then it crashes with the bug: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException**.

As an example if the example class uses **junit.Assert**, then when I run the project as an ordinary java application, it find this dependency, but when as plugin the below error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:798)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
```

Part of code that I think error is because of that is as below, and the whole code can be find in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/java-dependency-resolver/):

```
class ClassCollector extends Remapper {

static Set<Class<?>> getClassesUsedBy(final String name, final String prefix, File root) throws IOException {

final ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(name);
final Set<Class<?>> classes = new TreeSet<Class<?>> (new Comparator<Class<?>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare (final Class<?> o1, final Class<?> o2) {
         return o1.getName().compareTo (o2.getName());
    }
});

final Remapper remapper = new ClassCollector(classes, prefix, root);
final ClassWriter inner = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
final RemappingClassAdapter visitor = new RemappingClassAdapter(inner, remapper);
try {
    reader.accept(visitor, ClassReader.EXPAND_FRAMES);
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.toString();
}
return classes;
}
```

**Important**: when I initialized inner (as below) with **null**, then the program does not crash, but cannot detect all dependencies, and for example cannot detect assert dependency in the above example.

```
final ClassVisitor inner = null; //new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
```

Please let me know if any one knows why the program is correct as an ordinary java application, but crash as plugin.

Comment: I feel that I have answered your question: "Please let me know if any one knows why the program is correct as an ordinary java application, but crash as plugin." If you disagree, I'd like to understand why. If you don't disagree, I'd appreciate credit.

Comment: Yes, You answer is correct. The problem was not for the ASM and it is because class loader cannot find the class as it is not in the class path. To cope with the problem I add new path to class loader using Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(), and now it works. So, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClassReader(String name) uses the ClassLoader.loadSystemResourceAsStream() method to access the bytes for a requested class. If the classes you want to analyze are not in the class path, this won't work, since the class path is what loadSystemResourceAsStream searches.

Comment: That is right. But I do not know how to add classes to the class Path to fix the problem. As an example for the above error **junit.Assert**, the Junit is already added to the plugin as well as to the example program. In addition, I added example project as a dependency to the plugin, but still does not work.

Comment: @user3623718 that depends on what you mean by plugin.

Comment: By plugin I mean the program that should find dependencies for an input example class. In the above code "name" is the full name of class file such as (c:\project1\bin\clazz.class) that I want to find its dependency.

Comment: If you have the path to the dependency in question you can just create an InputStream for it and pass that to the ClassReader(InputStream) constructor.   edit - on re-reading your last comment, I realize this isn't a very helpful response. However, the point remains: if the classes you are trying to read are not already loaded or loadable by the system class loader, you have to tell ASM exactly where the byte code is, or make them available to the class loader.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I am looking: but how tell ASM to search for the byte codes in the whole project instead of searching only bin directory. When the project is an ordinary application, it searches the whole project and find dependencies (for example it can find a dependent jar file defined in the lib directory). But when the program is run as plugin it only searches bin directory where the input class is defined.

Comment: in this line: final Remapper remapper = new ClassCollector(classes, prefix, root);  the root is defined as project address. But it does not work and cannot find dependency (such as added jar file) defined outside of the bin directory.

Comment: I wish there were a simple way to do so. In the case where the project is an 'ordinary application', you are, whether you know it or not, providing additional input to ASM in the form of a ClassPath which includes all the dependencies. You *MUST* provide this information, in one form or another, in *ALL* cases, whether by including the dependent classes in the class path, or by providing enough input to your application to determine the full path of each dependent class, or an InputStream for each dependent class.

Comment: As far as Remapper goes, I don't think it is a way to provide input to ASM regarding byte code location.